# Can't connect to LAN

Tags: networking

I am new to Ubuntu using 14.04 I installed on a Dell SC440 and cannot get  it to connect to the Internet. I am using a power link and the lead light blinks as normal.

Any help most welcome.

Comment: Are you using Ethernet or Wireless?

Comment: How is your computer connected to the power link network? Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of the terminal commands `lsusb` (if over USB) and `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Ethernet` (if over PCI via Ethernet) as well as `LC_MESSAGES=POSIX nm-tool` (any connection type)? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Considering it is a laptop, try plugging it into your wall port (cat5e)If it connects through a wired connection, It might be your wireless driver. If this is the case, find your brand/model wireless card and find a Linux driver then install from there
If all else fails, just buy a wireless adaptor from a raspi retailer and you should be good;)